# Use function to check to see if item is in an array then remove that item from the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im creating a function that will check to see if items are in a previously created array and if they are, they will not only return them to a new array but remove them from the old array and replace them with new items.

I tried using the `splice` method but wasn't getting the right results.

```
let valuables = ['dilithium', 'gold', 'AE-35 unit', 'Legos', 'TI-89 calculator'];
let deckMops = function(itemArray){
  let emptyArray = [];
  for (i = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++)
    if (valuables.includes(itemArray[i])){
      emptyArray.push(itemArray[i]);
    }
    return emptyArray;
};
console.log(deckMops(['food', 'gold', 'Legos', 'air']));
console.log(valuables);
```

Expected output

- the function replaces `'gold'` and `'Legos'` in `arr = ['food', 'gold', 'Legos', 'air']`
- after calling the function, `valuables.includes('gold')` and `valuables.includes('Legos')` should be `false`
- `arr.length` should be 4

Comment: What do you want to replace the replaced items with?

Comment: So which two elements you want instead of `'gold'` and `'Legos'`?

Comment: Instead of pushing to new array why don't you update the existing array using index.

Comment: can you please clarify your expected output? What should the first `console.log()` give and what should the second `console.log()` give in your example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `.splice()` each time the element is found from `valuables` using `indexOf` after pushing it to `emptyArray` if removing the elements is the goal:

```js
let valuables = ['dilithium', 'gold', 'AE-35 unit', 'Legos', 'TI-89 calculator'];
let deckMops = function(itemArray){
  let emptyArray = [];
  for (i = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++)
    if (valuables.includes(itemArray[i])){
      emptyArray.push(itemArray[i]);
      valuables.splice(valuables.indexOf(itemArray[i]), 1);
    }
    return emptyArray;
};
console.log(deckMops(['food', 'gold', 'Legos', 'air']));
console.log(valuables);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out any items from `itemArray` which are not in `valuables` using `.filter()` and `includes()` (and store it in a variable called `ret`), and then reassign `valuables` to be equal to a filtered version of `valuables` which no longer includes the items found in `ret` like so:

```js
let valuables = ['dilithium', 'gold', 'AE-35 unit', 'Legos', 'TI-89 calculator'];
const deckMops = function(itemArray) {
  const ret = itemArray.filter(x => valuables.includes(x));
  valuables = valuables.filter(x => !ret.includes(x));
  return ret;
};
console.log(deckMops(['food', 'gold', 'Legos', 'air']));
console.log(valuables);
```